# Pass Parameter into Xamarin Forms Behaviour

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a Form in my app and I am using Behaviors for Client side Validation.
I want to pass a value into the behavior for a max Validator.
The Value is stored in my ViewModel and I have tried to pass the value into the behavior however it passes a zero into the behavior rather than the value.
I have tried using a hard-coded value and that works fine.

My question is:
Is it possible for the ViewModel property to be passed into the behavior?

XAML:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding EventSubscription.Attendees, Mode=TwoWay }"  WidthRequest="50"   x:Name="attendees"  >
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:NullEntryValidationBehaviour x:Name="GroupValidator"/>
        <behaviours:MaxAttendeesValidationBehaviour Max="{Binding EventSubscription.RemainingPlaces, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

C# Behaviour:

```
public class MaxAttendeesValidationBehaviour : Behavior<Entry>
{
    
    public static BindableProperty IntProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MaxAttendeesValidationBehaviour, string>(tc => tc.MaxAttendeesAllowed, string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string MaxAttendeesAllowed
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(IntProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(IntProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    }

    void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsValid = false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            IsValid = true;//Int32.Parse(e.NewTextValue) <= MaxAttendeesAllowed;
        }                     
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }  
  
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
public class MaxValueEntry : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public int Max { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.NewTextValue.Length > Max)
            ((Entry)sender).TextColor = Color.Red;
        else
            ((Entry)sender).TextColor = Color.Default;
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml, you add the parameter like this:

```
  <Entry>
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <behaviors:MaxValueEntry Max="3"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
```

If you need to bind the value from the view model, you should create a bindable property for `Max`

like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MaxProperty =
BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Max", typeof(int), typeof(MaxValueEntry), 0);

public int Max
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MaxProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MaxProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: the same issue occurs where by the Bindable property is always 0. For some reason the property is not being passed to the behaviour

Comment: No sure if still needed, but may serve for future devs coming here. Behaviors, by design, don't propagate the BindingContext of the view, so they can be reused across multiple views and cause less pressure on GC. See [1] and [2]. If you go through the Xamarin forums post, you'll find a link to a gist [3] that may help.




  [1]: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/101682
  [2]: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26521
  [3]: https://gist.github.com/Yortw/f4b1220296de0a1d53ce

Comment: How do you pass in the parameter in, in the view from a collection using binding? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: For anyone that finds this in the future, you need to manually add the binding context in the behavior : 

protected override void OnAttachedTo(BindableObject bindable) { base.OnAttachedTo(bindable); bindable.BindingContextChanged += (sender, _) => this.BindingContext = ((BindableObject)sender).BindingContext; }